# Only publishing data if a field is true

Tags: mongodb, meteor

at the moment I am publishing only specific fields to a certain page, I have also created an index to help sort my collection, but I am having trouble with only returning items if a "check" field is true. For example.

```
    return collection.find({},{
       sort: { rank: 1, scores: 1 },
       fields: {
           "_id": 1, "name": 1, etc..
       }
   });
```

But I am wanting to return items that only have "check" : true, I have tried to put in **"check": { $eq: true }** just below the **sort** but still no luck. Any help would be great thanks. By the way, my index was

```
    collection.rawCollection().createIndex({ "rank": 1, "scores": 1 });
```

Just in case that is any help.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are finding all documents.

You want something more like this:

```
collection.find({check: true},{
       sort: { rank: 1, scores: 1 },
       fields: {
           "_id": 1, "name": 1, etc..
       }
   });
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Cool thanks for that, I also had to add the "check" field to the fields object. Thanks again!

Comment: Yea the fields object is used to get the fields you actually want to pull out of the database. The expression is used just to match on the objects you want to look at in the first place.